# VMware tools not installing on Windows 7 ultimate. VMware workstation pro

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

So, I made a windows 7 virtual machine and VMware tools will not install. It just fails to install loads of stuff. I use custom and unselect the stuff that fails to install. It just rolls back. I'm using VMware workstation pro btw. Windows update just fails to check for updates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make Sure Windows 7 is fully up to date (SP 1 plus all updates).  Then install VMware Tools manually.  https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/11.3.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-391BE4BF-89A9-4DC3-85E7-3D45F5124BC7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install "Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3033929)"

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46148

You should now be able to boot into VMware Windows 7

Video Reference:

How to fix VMware tools can't install in windows 7 (with proof)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpfrc-ncSLw